# gitlab runner run in background on Ubuntu startUp

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a problem. Gitlab Ci/CD works perfect and changes from repo comes to webserber if i previously connect via ssh to webserver and type

```
gitlab-runner run
```

I try to add autoload to `sudo systemctl enable --now gitlab-runner`. After restart Runner is visible from GitLab admin panel and it is green, but if i push to repo changes, changes not updated till command `gitlab-runner run` is run on webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution with Ubuntu (Linux) run command

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Important -> **sudo** give possibility run crontab tasks as root (sudoer user)
Add in crontab tasks command below

```
@reboot sudo gitlab-runner run
```

On each server reboot gitlab-runner will be started

Answer (score 2):

Acording to the official giltab doc (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/)

```bash
gitlab-runner start
```

"This command starts the GitLab Runner service."

Answer (score 1):

Hello maybe this might help you , what I did was

```
sudo gitlab-runner run&
```

using '&' it will start it in the background and even if you close you ssh session it will still be there, it will only stop if the server restarts or closes